# Data loss when request get cancelled using AJAX in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending a big amount of data with POST using ajax in Laravel. 
When I send request rapidly and redirect the page to another page then data is getting lost when ajax call is canceled or aborted.

I've mentioned the process below:

1. Send ajax request rapidly
2. Then before responding to latest request of ajax call by browser I redirect to another page
3. Then I check the data which is storing when ajax call happen. I found the data is lost.

**Below is the code**

```
<script>
 var cssData = $('.css-textarea').val();
 $.ajax({
   url: '/save-data',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {cssData: cssData},
   success:function(response){
      //do something after success
   }    
 });
</script>
```

**PHP/Laravel Code**

```
public function saveCssData(){   
   $data = Input::get();
   $cssData =  $data['cssData'];        
   //Do something to save data
    $db->cssData = $cssData;
    $db->save();
}
```

Please do not assume the exact code because I've given an example. 
This code works fine but when I send rapid calls by ajax and before getting a response, I redirect to another page then the data is lost. I've set enough post_max_size and other configurations but still, it's not fixed

**Example of Input which I am sending by ajax request**

```
{
 "testCss":
  " #class{background:#fff}../*big amount data */...
    #testDiv{color:#000}
   "
}
```

**Example of The Output which I am receiving in database which is lost**

```
{
 "testCss":
  " #class{background:#fff}../*big amount data */...
    #testDiv{col
```

You can see the data is lost in output. This issue is appearing at sometimes but I noticed that when I request rapidly with ajax and abort the requests by redirecting to another page then it's appearing but don't know how to fix this.

Comment: check the length of column in your database, You might have given column datatype is VARCHAR and length is 80, if size is limited then increase the length of change the datatype to TEXT

Comment: @PankajMakwana I've checked, it's fine, it's a TEXT already. I said this issue occurred sometimes. Otherwise, it's storing the data well, no data loss. But I noticed when I make a rapid request or single request and before completing the request I redirect to another page, then browser automatically cancels the request, then the issue of data loss is appearing.

Comment: can you define "when I send rapid calls by ajax and before getting a response"? if you send too many calls they may not even leave your browser before redirect occurs. you should check network in dev tools and see if all calls are sent to the server. To be safe, send calls as promises and redirect only when done.